# How can I stop the breadcrumb module from duplicating categories

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have the standard breadcrumb module loaded on my site but the links it is generating is displaying a duplicate of the categories.

For example an article I have called overview is attached to the category Africa which in turn is attached to the category destinations.

I have used Simple Custom Router to generate a user friendly URL for the page which is home/destinations/africa/overview. This URL correctly loads the article. However the breadcrumbs shows up as: home\destinations\africa\destinations\africa\overview.

I have researched and found that particularly in Joomla 1.7 this was an issue. However, I am using Joomla 3.3 and cannot find any 'solution' that can help me.

Comment: Can you link to the info on the issue you found?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try BreadCrumbs Advanced:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/breadcrumbs-advanced

We used a similar extension called Breadcrumbs Manager, but it appears to have been removed from the JED, but I suspect this would work the same way.

Comment: the link is broken